# How can I show toastr message after form update?

Tags: laravel, octobercms, flash-message, toastr

I have a form component and it has a flash message after save data.
The form works fine, but the flash message shows just loading the form page not after update the page.
How can I make this work right?

I'm using Octobercms framework.

In my form component >

```php
public function onUpdate()
  {
      $promotionData = PromotionData::where('idx', Input::get('idx'))->first();

      $promotionData->pm_title = Input::get('pm_title');
      $promotionData->pm_code = Input::get('pm_code');
      $promotionData->mem_id = Input::get('mem_id');
      $promotionData->mem_name = Input::get('mem_name');
      $promotionData->pm_target = Input::get('pm_target');
      $promotionData->pm_comment = Input::get('pm_comment');
      $promotionData->pm_content = Input::get('pm_content');

      //print_r($promotionData->pm_content);

      $promotionData->save();

      Flash::success('Update success');

      if ($redirect = $this->makeRedirection()) {
          return $redirect;
      }

  }
```

In my page >

```php
<div class="method">

      {% component 'Toastr' %}

        <div class="col-md-12 margin-0">

          {% component promotionForm ~ '::update' %}

        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using giving `session` instead of `Flash` directly, 
Replace your code from

```
Flash::success('Update success');
```

to

```
Session::flash('Update success');
```

Comment: I changed the code and now it doesn't show any message.

Answer (score 0):

I've got it. It was because I was using {{ form_ajax() }}. I edit it {{ form_open({ request: 'onUpdate'}) }}, and the flash works right.